# How do I backend validate multiple checkboxes (Blazor)?

Tags: sql, razor, checkbox, blazor

In my razor page is a form with 3 checkboxes. One must be selected in order for the submission to save.
I can front end validate this all day but the project now requires backend validation. Seems like a supposedly easy task but I'm stuck!

In SQL I have three bools set to 0. The validation must check to see if one is true before submitting. The Blazor code is below.

```
PendingModel:

public string CriteriaMessage{get;set;}

public bool checkboxA{ get; set; }
public bool checkboxB{ get; set; }
public bool checkboxC{ get; set; }

PendingViewModel:

[NotMapped]
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You must select at least one!")]
public bool validateCheckbox
{
    get { return (checkboxA|| checkboxB|| checkboxC); }
}

Pending.razor:
 
<InputTextArea class="" id="" @bind-Value="PendingViewModel.CriteriaMessage" />
<ValidationMessage For = "@(()=>@PendingViewModel.CriteriaMessage)" />

 <InputCheckbox class="" id="" @bind-Value="PendingViewModel.checkboxA" />
 <InputCheckbox class="" id="" @bind-Value="PendingViewModel.checkboxB" />
 <InputCheckbox class="" id="" @bind-Value="PendingViewModel.checkboxC" />
<ValidationMessage For = "@(()=>@PendingViewModel.validateCheckbox)" />

@code{
public void Save(
{
   PendingViewModel = new();
}
}
```

Comment: I seem no backend in your code.   Do you have a data pipeline?  What is it.   Where in it do you want to validate.  Who gets the validation result and how?  What happens on fail?  Easy, it is not.

Comment: Currently I have two requirements for validation. I have textbox that requires a character to validate AND I need to require one of the three checkboxes to OnValidSubmit. The user, currently, can click Save and both error messages appear. But if the user just enters text in the textbox and clicks Save it validates. I don't know why it  hit the error message but submits without validating.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest FluentValidation for forms. It saves time and can be both applied on frontend and backend. Wrap your checkbox in DTO class. And add a form to your blazor component.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public bool CheckboxA { get; set; }
    public bool CheckboxB { get; set; }
    public bool CheckboxC { get; set; }
}
public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x)
            .Must(x => x.CheckboxA || x.CheckboxB || x.CheckboxC)
            .WithMessage("At least one checkbox must be checked.");
        //Add your own rules
    }
}

//Usage - Later in a backend

var validator = new MyCheckboxModelValidator();
var results = validator.Validate(myModel);
```

For blazor EditForms here is library with examples :
https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of how to do your validation in the form.  There's lots of inline commentary to explain what I'm doing.  I've abandoned using the form `OnValidSubmit` and `OnInvalidSubmit` callbacks and do the validation manually in `OnSubmit`.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<EditForm EditContext="_editContext" OnSubmit="OnSubmitAsync">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div>
        <InputCheckbox class="" @bind-Value="_model.checkboxA" /> A
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputCheckbox class="" @bind-Value="_model.checkboxB" /> B
    </div>
    <div>
        <InputCheckbox class="" @bind-Value="_model.checkboxC" /> C
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Model _model = new();
    private EditContext? _editContext;
    private ValidationMessageStore? _validationMessageStore;

    private FieldIdentifier checkboxAFi;
    private FieldIdentifier checkboxBFi;
    private FieldIdentifier checkboxCFi;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // normally get the model here
        
        _editContext = new(_model);

        // Validation Message store is a strange beast
        // Your need to get your own read/write pen
        _validationMessageStore = new(_editContext);

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_editContext);

        // Create the Field Identifiers for our checkboxes 
        checkboxAFi = new FieldIdentifier(_model, "checkboxA");
        checkboxBFi = new FieldIdentifier(_model, "checkboxB");
        checkboxCFi = new FieldIdentifier(_model, "checkboxC");

        // Wire up to the Edit contexts Field Changed event so we can update the checkbox validation on a change
        _editContext.OnFieldChanged += this.OnFieldChanged;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // Submit method called,
    private async Task OnSubmitAsync()
    {
        // Get the form and checkbox validation
        var formValid = _editContext?.Validate() ?? false;
        var checkBoxesValid = ValidateCheckboxes();

        // Only save if valid
        if (formValid && checkBoxesValid)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            // Do your save
        }
    }

    // Validate the checkboxes
    public bool ValidateCheckboxes()
    {
        // Do we have a selected box
        var checkBoxesValid = _model.checkboxA || _model.checkboxB || _model.checkboxC;

        // Clear our message
        _validationMessageStore?.Clear(checkboxAFi);

        // Add a message is we don't have one selected
        if (!checkBoxesValid)
        {
            _validationMessageStore?.Add(checkboxAFi, "At least one Checkbox must be selected");
        }

        return checkBoxesValid;
    }

    public void OnFieldChanged(object? sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool trip = false;

        // Check if one of the checkboxes has been changed
        if (e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName == checkboxAFi.FieldName)
            trip = true;
        if (e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName == checkboxBFi.FieldName)
            trip = true;
        if (e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName == checkboxCFi.FieldName)
            trip = true;

        // run validation is we have a checkbox change
        if (trip)
            ValidateCheckboxes();
    }


    public class Model
    {
        public string? CriteriaMessage { get; set; }

        public bool checkboxA { get; set; }
        public bool checkboxB { get; set; }
        public bool checkboxC { get; set; }
    }
}
```